# Show every file in a directory, but don't show files that are currently being copied

Tags: c#, file

I have a function that checks every file in a directory and writes a list to the console. The problem is, I don't want it to include files that are currently being copied to the directory, I only want it to show the files that are complete. How do I do that? Here is my code:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\folder"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
        }
```

Comment: Is your application copying the files? If so, you can add the name of each file being copied to a list, and print out the ones that are not in the list.

Comment: "Currently being copied" what is the definition of "Current" in the context of your question?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). Why do you care? How would knowing the answer help you? What will happen if a file was not being "copied to" the directory when you created your list, but was after being shown to "the console"?

Answer (score 3):

There's really no way to tell "being copied" vs "locked for writing by something". Relevant: [How to check for file lock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c) and [Can I simply 'read' a file that is in use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203837/can-i-simply-read-a-file-that-is-in-use)

If you want to simply display a list of files that are not open for writing, you can do that by attempting to open them:

```
foreach (string file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\folder"))
{
   try {
     using (var file = file.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite) {
       Console.WriteLine(file);
     }
   } catch {
     // file is in use
     continue;
   }
}
```

However -- lots of caveats.

- Immediately after displaying the filename (end of the `using` block) the file could be opened by something else
- The process writing the file may have used FileShare.Read which means the call will succeed, despite it being written to.

---

I'm not sure what exactly you're up to here, but it sounds like two processes sharing a queue directory: one writing, one reading/processing. The biggest challenge is that writing a file takes time, and so your "reading" process ends up picking it up and trying to read it before the whole file is there, which will fail in some way depending on the sharing mode, how your apps are written, etc.

A common pattern to deal with this situation is to use an atomic file operation like `Move`:

- Do the (slow) write/copy operation to a temporary directory that's on the **same file system** (very important) as the queue directory
- Once complete, do a Move from the temporary directory to the queue directory.

Since move is atomic, the file will either not be there, or it will be 100% there -- there is no opportunity for the "reading" process to ever see the file while it's partially there.

Note that if you do the move across file systems, it will act the same as a copy.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "current files being copied" list stored anywhere in Windows/.NET/whatever. Probably the most you could do is attempt to open each file for append and see if you get an exception. Depending on the size and location of your directory, and on the security setup, that may not be an option.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a clean way to do this, but this... works...

```
foreach (var file in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Folder").GetFiles())
{
    try
    {
        file.OpenRead();
    }
    catch
    {
        continue;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
}
```