# C# - Catching Database error code to handle

Tags: c#, oracle, error-handling

In my database I've crated a unique constraint that controls the uniqueness of IDTYPE and IDNO pairs. So there cannot be a second row that has IDTYPE of 1 and IDNO of 11232. Obviously if I violate this my application will crash with oracle unique constraint error. How can I catch this and any other error because I do not want to run a query to check if there's any other row having the same value of IDNO and IDTYPE. If I can catch this error I can show my own description instead of Oracle's one that only we programmers can understand.

Comment: Here's a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091199/using-unique-key-in-sql-with-or-without-try-catch-as-a-valid-way-to-verify-integ) for SQL Server approach (both the question and answers tell you how to deal with it) but it should be the same for Oracle.

Comment: Yeah, that'll do the job I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I haven't misunderstood, you're looking for a try-catch statement, just like this

```
try { //code to access DB }
catch (Exception e) { //do some stuff }
```