# FileIO in win 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-8

I have to log my application events and exceptions in a file in win 8 app in documents folder

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary;
```

The problem is when I call WriteToFile function one after other there is an access is denied exception because the file is still being used.
Is there a way to make this work

```
public async void WriteToFile(string log)
            {
                try
                {

                    StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
                    //StorageFile sampleFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("dataFile.txt");
                    IRandomAccessStream writeStream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);
                    IOutputStream outputStream = writeStream.GetOutputStreamAt(writeStream.Size);
                    DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream);
                    dataWriter.WriteString(log);

                    dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask().Wait();
                    outputStream.FlushAsync().AsTask().Wait();

                }
                finally
                {

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you forgot to close the Stream after write operation.
The file will be locked until you close the Stream.

```
dataWriter.Close();
```

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datawriter.close)

or use the "using" Keyword like this:

```
 using(DataWriter dataWriter = new DataWriter(outputStream)) 
 {
       dataWriter.WriteString(log);
       dataWriter.StoreAsync().AsTask().Wait(); 
 }
```

It's a good idea to check if the file is locked, so you didn't get an exception.

[How to Check for locked file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c)

Greetings, hope it helps

Comment: Tried this but still the same I guess will need to queue all the tasks.

Comment: Yea, parallel access to file is complicated. It's easier with a serial access :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following

```
dataWriter.Dispose();
await outputStream.FlushAsync();
await stream.FlushAsync();
```

Comment: Tried this but still the same I guess will need to queue all the tasks.