# What is the best way to lock a file to prevent multiple users from accessing it

Tags: c#, xml, lockfile

I have a windows form app in which users can open, create and save xml files. Files are typically saved to a network folder. I need to make sure a given file can only be opened by one user at a time. The xml file is loaded into a tree control and is saved frequently during a session. (almost any time a tree node is clicked)
I'm opening the file like this:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(m_Filename, FileMode.Open);
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseBoardTest));
m_TestNodes = (BaseBoardTest)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
fs.Close();
```

Saving like this:

```
TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseBoardTest));
serializer.Serialize(writer, m_TestNodes);
writer.Close();
```

I'd like to display a message stating which user/computer name has the file open if another user tries to open it or overwrite it via a save as.
I am considering creating a lock file when a file is opened.
Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How about closing the file only after you're done with it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock-in-c

Answer (score 2):

A lock file will be the only way if you want to display additional information.

Comment: Yes, it would be valuable to let users know who has the file open.

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to prevent users from opening the file when it's been opened by another user, you will need the `FileShare.None` enum.

You should replace

```
new FileStream(m_Filename, FileMode.Open);
```

with

```
new FileStream(m_Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None)
```

More information on FileShare.None can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx

**Note:** Be sure to catch any exceptions raised when attempting to open the file.  If one user has opened the file, then any subsequent request to open the file will raise a `System.IO.IOException` until the file has been closed.

Answer (score 0):

You could handle that by only locking write access, thereby allowing others to still read the file:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(m_Filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
   XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fs);
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseBoardTest));
   m_TestNodes = (BaseBoardTest)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
   fs.Close();

   TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filename);
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(BaseBoardTest));
   serializer.Serialize(writer, m_TestNodes);
   writer.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from a synchronized logger functionality. It is unaccessible until the write has completed and is thread safe.

```
internal class WriteToLockedFile
    {
        internal static string Uri { get; set ; }
        private static readonly object _syncObject = new object();

        public static void WriteToFile(string logMessage)
        {
            using (var stream = TextWriter.Synchronized( File.AppendText(Uri)))
            {
                lock (_syncObject) 
                {
                    stream.WriteLine(" {0}", logMessage); stream.Flush(); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
```