# How to delete a specific file from folder using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

here's the deal I got a datagridviewer which is called gridview1 and a fileupload1 when i upload a file it updates the gridview1 and table in database with the file name and path and stores the said file in folder "Mag"... but now what i want to do is the reverse i got how to use the gridview to delete the table entry but deleting the file from folder "Mag" is not working have used the following code in C# or codebehind

```
protected void GridView1_Del(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{
    string DeleteThis = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
    string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"i:/Website/WebSite3/Mag/");

    foreach (string file in Files)
    {
        if (file.ToUpper().Contains(DeleteThis.ToUpper()))
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
    }
}
```

it gives me error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

pls tell me what im doing wrong am new and don't have to in depth understanding of the platform so any and all help will be appreciated
thanks in advance
Mark

Here is the answer i found Thanks Tammy and everyone else for all the answers

Ok  here the deal target function delete file details from gridview and database table and file from project folder where the file is stored

in script section of gridview you would want to include

```
OnRowDeleting="FuntionName"
```

Not

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged = "FuntionName"
```

or

```
OnRowDeleted="FuntionName"
```

then in C# code(codebehind)

```
protected void FuntionName(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
// storing value from cell
        TableCell cell = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0];

// full path required
        string fileName = ("i:/Website/WebSite3/Mag/" + cell.Text); 

    if(fileName != null || fileName != string.Empty)
    {
       if((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))) 
       {
           System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
       }

     }
  }
```

And just for added reference for those who want to learn

OnRowDeleting="FuntionName" is for just before deleting a row you can cancel deleting or run functions on the data like i did

OnRowDeleted="FuntionName" it directly deletes

Comment: At what like you are getting exception?

Comment: On which line is it giving the exception? `GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text` looks suspicious to me

Comment: does this line from your code string DeleteThis = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
 returns you the correct file path?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: Try this:  if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)))
               System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);

Comment: Thanks so much @گلی you code works fine.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is how I delete files

```
if ((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName)))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);
}
```

Also make sure that the file name you are passing in your delete, is the accurate path

**EDIT**

You could use the following event instead as well or just use the code in this snippet and use in your method

```
void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

    // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
    GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;

    //Debug this line and see what value is returned if it contains the full path.
    //If it does not contain the full path then add the path to the string.
    string fileName = row.Cells[0].Text 

    if(fileName != null || fileName != string.empty)
    {
       if((System.IO.File.Exists(fileName))
           System.IO.File.Delete(fileName);

     }
  }
```

Comment: In a ASP.Net scenario... BP to first [check the file is not in use](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3202085/495455) before deleting.

Comment: it is asp.net scenario and the file will not be in use a the time also @tammy will you said procedure delete file from mentioned folder or do i have to add path for that to happen

Comment: Yes if i understand correctly,  you will have to add path for that to happen

Comment: @jeremey Yes In my case it assumed the file is not being current used but I agree its good practice to check for locks if thats the requirement.

Comment: ok so just to confirm (oh and tell me if im getting irritating ill shutup) if my folder is "Mag" and my file name is stored in selected row then can i do this? `code` if ((System.IO.File.Exists("Mag/"+GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text)))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("Mag/"+GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text);
        }

Comment: well, get the selected file name from the row and store it to a string. Debug and see what the value is if it already has the folder info. then make necessary changes to the path

Comment: I dont think you need this line. string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(@"i:/Website/WebSite3/Mag/");
Just pass the file name from the grid cell to If File.Exists and make sure the path is valid.

Comment: Ok i  found the answer and got to admit i was being kindda dumb and not using the brain that was apparently there in my head lol for all those try to do the same thing i was see the answer i have given to my own question and thank Tammy could not have figured it out without your help

Comment: You can use `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)` instead `fileName != null || fileName != string.empty`

Answer (score 1):

Check the GridView1.SelectedRow is not null:

```
if (GridView1.SelectedRow == null) return;
string DeleteThis = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
```

Comment: SelectedRow isn't a collection so checking it for null would be a better tips.

Answer (score 1):

In my project i am using ajax and i create a web method in my code behind like this

in front

```
 $("#attachedfiles a").live("click", function () {
            var row = $(this).closest("tr");
            var fileName = $("td", row).eq(0).html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "SendEmail.aspx/RemoveFile",
                data: '{fileName: "' + fileName + '" }',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.d);
                }
            });
            row.remove();
        });
```

in code behind

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static void RemoveFile(string fileName)
        {
            List<HttpPostedFile> files = (List<HttpPostedFile>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Files"];
            files.RemoveAll(f => f.FileName.ToLower().EndsWith(fileName.ToLower()));

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Employee/uploads/" + fileName)))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Employee/uploads/" + fileName));
            }
        }
```

i think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Delete any or specific file type(for example ".bak") from a path.
See demo code below -

```
class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
            {

            // Specify the starting folder on the command line, or in 
            TraverseTree(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["folderPath"]);

            // Specify the starting folder on the command line, or in 
            // Visual Studio in the Project > Properties > Debug pane.
            //TraverseTree(args[0]);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
            }

        public static void TraverseTree(string root)
            {

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(root))
                return;

            // Data structure to hold names of subfolders to be
            // examined for files.
            Stack<string> dirs = new Stack<string>(20);

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(root))
                {
                return;
                }

            dirs.Push(root);

            while (dirs.Count > 0)
                {
                string currentDir = dirs.Pop();
                string[] subDirs;
                try
                    {
                    subDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(currentDir);
                    }

                // An UnauthorizedAccessException exception will be thrown if we do not have
                // discovery permission on a folder or file. It may or may not be acceptable 
                // to ignore the exception and continue enumerating the remaining files and 
                // folders. It is also possible (but unlikely) that a DirectoryNotFound exception 
                // will be raised. This will happen if currentDir has been deleted by
                // another application or thread after our call to Directory.Exists. The 
                // choice of which exceptions to catch depends entirely on the specific task 
                // you are intending to perform and also on how much you know with certainty 
                // about the systems on which this code will run.
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                    }
                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                    }

                IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = null;
                try
                    {
                    //get only .bak file
                    var directory = new DirectoryInfo(currentDir);
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-15);
                    files = directory.GetFiles("*.bak").Where(file => file.CreationTime <= date);
                    }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                    }
                catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException e)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    continue;
                    }

                // Perform the required action on each file here.
                // Modify this block to perform your required task.
                foreach (FileInfo file in files)
                    {
                    try
                        {
                        // Perform whatever action is required in your scenario.
                        file.Delete();
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}, {2} was successfully deleted.", file.Name, file.Length, file.CreationTime);
                        }
                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException e)
                        {
                        // If file was deleted by a separate application
                        //  or thread since the call to TraverseTree()
                        // then just continue.
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        continue;
                        }
                    }

                // Push the subdirectories onto the stack for traversal.
                // This could also be done before handing the files.
                foreach (string str in subDirs)
                    dirs.Push(str);
                }
            }
        }
```

for more reference -
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
string sourceDir = @"c:\current";
string backupDir = @"c:\archives\2008";

try
{
    string[] picList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.jpg");
    string[] txtList = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir, "*.txt");

    // Copy picture files. 
    foreach (string f in picList)
    {
        // Remove path from the file name. 
        string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

        // Use the Path.Combine method to safely append the file name to the path. 
        // Will overwrite if the destination file already exists.
        File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName), true);
    }

    // Copy text files. 
    foreach (string f in txtList)
    {

        // Remove path from the file name. 
        string fName = f.Substring(sourceDir.Length + 1);

        try
        {
            // Will not overwrite if the destination file already exists.
            File.Copy(Path.Combine(sourceDir, fName), Path.Combine(backupDir, fName));
        }

        // Catch exception if the file was already copied. 
        catch (IOException copyError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(copyError.Message);
        }
    }

    // Delete source files that were copied. 
    foreach (string f in txtList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
    foreach (string f in picList)
    {
        File.Delete(f);
    }
}

catch (DirectoryNotFoundException dirNotFound)
{
    Console.WriteLine(dirNotFound.Message);
}
```