# Send Email as attachment then delete

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package where I am generating a file and sending it to a user, that works all well.  however, they want the date in the file name, and I don't want to have a bunch of old daily files sitting in my directory, so I try to delete the file after sending (all of this is done is a script task).

```
System.IO.File.Delete(DestinationName);
```

Now, the problem is, I get an error saying it can't delete because the file is in use by another process (the sending of the email) so I thought to make it wait a bit:

```
//wait a minute before deleting 
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
System.IO.File.Delete(DestinationName);
```

By this time I have recieved the email, however, the process is still holding on to the file.  How do I get the email to let go?  Do i need to put this in its own Script Task?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock

Comment: quick fix could be to delete the file from outside of the ssis package. F.i: Define a seperate step in the job starting your package. Your package will be done so the file handle will most likely be gone.

Comment: My current solution is to wait till the next day to delete the file in my SSIS package while i generate a new one to email.

Comment: Also Found that a using took care of the issue as well.  I did try it before, but didn't work the first time, might of been some other error i didn't notice

Comment: Could you use a file system task to do the deletion instead of the script?