# using a Lock on a log Writer to Prevent Errors

Tags: c#, locking, task-parallel-library, task

I am downloading Images from the web using a foreach and tasks, and saving them locally.
After doing this I then write to a log saying the file name downloaded etc. The problem is I foresee that two tasks may try to write to the log at the same time causing an error.
I would like to be able to lock the Log if any other Task is writing to it but I'm not sure how?
So far I have:

```
 int filesDownloaded = 0;
 foreach (var fileName in ListOfFileNames)
 {
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         //Download File
     }
     lock (thislock)
     {
          Log.WriteLine(string.Format("Downloaded File: {0}", f.FullName), Log.Status.Success); 
     }
     filesDownloaded++;
 }
```

Do I need to lock the `filesDownloaded` variable, or as this is a simple ++ operation does it not matter?

**EDIT**

**Static Log Class:**

```
public enum Status
{
    Info,
    Error,
    Success
}

private static string Directory { get; set; }

public static void CheckandCreateLogDirectory(string directoryPath)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(directoryPath))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
    }
    Directory = directoryPath;
}

public static void WriteLine(string writeLine, Status status)
{
    if (Directory == null)
    {
        CheckandCreateLogDirectory(".\\Log\\"); 
    }
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Directory + "Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".log", true))
    {
        objWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, status.ToString(), writeLine));             
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your Log.WriteLine refers to but you should probably lock the log file and then release it when logging is done. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3202085/668521

Comment: I understand the method and will probably implement it however how would I implement it as a lock? would I just use a while loop and have that method as the Boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code there are two things that come to mind:

1) Move your locking into the WriteLine() method - no point having to repeat the code every time you want to log something

```
private static object _lockMe = new object();
public static void WriteLine(string writeLine, Status status)
{
    lock(_lockMe)
    {
        if (Directory == null)
        {
            CheckandCreateLogDirectory(".\\Log\\"); 
        }
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(Directory + "Log" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy") + ".log", true))
        {
            objWriter.WriteLine(string.Format("[{0}] {1}\t{2}", DateTime.Now, status.ToString(), writeLine));             
        }
    }
}
```

2) You're downloading the file in a worker thread, but updating the log once you've queued up the worker - this will be BEFORE the file has downloaded. As a result, I'd move the logging INTO the worker thread, as follows:

```
int filesDownloaded = 0;
foreach (var fileName in ListOfFileNames)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew((path) =>
    {
        DownloadMyFile(path);
        Log.WriteLine(string.Format("Downloaded File: {0}",path), Log.Status.Success); 
        lock (thislock)
        {
            filesDownloaded++;
        }
    }, fileName);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, Works a charm. Thank you for the insight

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to lock the filesDownloaded variable, or as this is a simple
>   ++ operation does it not matter?

Yes, but better still use `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment`. This must be done in the scope of your task or via a continuation, else you are going to experience timing issues. (The download count is not going to match the files you are expecting in the destination)

---

Do not "lock" around your logging code (client). Protect access to the file in the logger (the Log class).  Here I would recommend a `System.Threading.Mutex` in case more than one process attempts to write to a single file (as if you had more than one instance of the application running).