# Sharing Violation from Program That Was Launched Using Process Start From WinForms

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to offer customers the ability to edit image files that are on a network drive by using ProcessStart within a WinForms application to launch the editing program for the file.  It launches the editing program just fine with the image; however, it will not allow them to save changes resulting in an error:

`A sharing violation occurred while accessing [File location and Name].`

If I keep the launched editing application open and close the WinForms application that launched the editor and then attempt to save the changes, it allows the changes to be saved 100% of the time without a problem.  Believing that the `ProcessStart` was not actually launching the process in a decoupled thread, I tried to launch the editing application using a new thread and that resulted in the same situation.  How can I launch the editing program from the WinForms app as a standalone, decoupled, program so the user can save the changes without closing the WinForms application?  I appreciate any insight into what I am not doing or not considering as an option.

This is the method I am calling to launch the editing program.  The `ProcessExe` is the name of the editing program on the users machines, the `workingDirectory` is the same value as the network file location, and the `args` is the fileLocation and Name

```
    public static void RunProcess(string ProcessExe, string workingDirectory, params string[] args)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.Arguments = HelperFunctions.EscapeArguments(args); //format the arguments correctly.
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.FileName = App.Shared.HelperFunctions.FindExePath(ProcessExe); //Name of the program to be opened
            //Tried setting the working directory to %USERPROFILE%\Documents and no difference
            startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo;
            //myProcess.Start(); //Tried this straight forward method call and it failed
            //Tried to use a new thread
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate { myProcess.Start(); }));
            //Tried without setting the apartment state, and setting as MTA and STA with the same result
            thread.TrySetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Calling Code:

```
    private void pbxImage_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strImageNum = BDL.Data["ImageNumber"].ToString();
            string strDirectory = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageLocation"];
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            fileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}", strDirectory, strImageNum, ".jpg");
            HelperFunctions.RunProcess("mspaint.exe", strDirectory, fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I used the code from VDohnal ([stackoverflow.com/a/20623302/2224701](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock/20623302)) and verified that the image file was in fact locked by the host WinForms application.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a threading problem.  Sounds like your program has a lock on the image file.  You aren't showing us that code.

Comment: Use this code to find out what process exactly locks the file http://stackoverflow.com/a/20623302/2224701

Comment: I will try out the code from the link.  You are correct that the program creates a lock on the image file when it launches the ProcessStart.  As far as the calling code goes it is a simple ButtonClick event"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Garth J. Lancaster.  Garth pointed out that I was using Picture.Load(file) to display the image in the WinForms application.  The act of doing that locked the image file; so, when I then tried to open the image file into MS Paint with the click event the file was already locked creating a sharing condition.  The solution was to create a bitmap from a byte[] from the image file and using Picture.Image = bitmap.  I was not aware that the Picture.Load() created a lock on the source image file.