# Have program execution switch between computers/servers

Tags: windows, server, alternate

I've got two servers and a program that I want to run on them (*not* necessarily simultaneously).

Let's call one server "SA" and the other one "SB".

SB is a backup for SA, and I want that while my program is executing on SA, if SA fails then the program will immediately pick up where it left off and continue executing on SB.

What is the easiest way I can accomplish this?

Comment: You'd have to persist your data in a shared location.  Then maybe SB watches the database and if something isn't written for 1 minute (or whatever your interval is) it will kick on and read the database to figure out what it is working on.

Comment: You can't. Your expectations are unrealistic. You can run an app on the second computer and have it load state from the first, but they can't execute each other's code seamlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably a bunch of ways that this could be done, but I'd use an exclusive file lock to do it.  To make that happen, you need enough network connectivity between the two servers that both could open a file for writing to.

Your basic algorithm (pseudocode) goes like this:

```
File f;
while (true) {
    myTurn = false
    try {
        Open Network file for writing
        myTurn = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // not logging anything because this is expected.
        // you might log that you tried maybe
        myTurn = false;
    }
    if ( myTurn ) {
        Do all of your actual work here.
        loop many times if that's what you're doing.  
        don't exit this bit until your server wants to shut down
          (or crashes).
        But don't close the file
    }
}
```

Basically what happens is that your app tries to open a file exclusively.

If it can't open it, then the other server is locked, so this server should stay quiet.

If it *can* open the file, then the other server is not running and this server should do the work.

For this to work, it's absolutely essential that the "work" routine, does not *hang* - as long as the other server's process is active, it will hang onto that network file lock.  So if the other server goes into an infinite loop, you'll be out of luck.

And remember, both servers are trying to open the same network file.  If they're trying to open a local file, it's not going to work.

This question has an example that you could probably re-use:
[Getting notified when a file lock is released](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205450/getting-notified-when-a-file-lock-is-released)