# visual basic opening a spreadsheet and then saving it; sometimes the file is locked

Tags: excel, vba

I write Visual Basic (not VBA) programs that access Microsoft Excel
spreadsheets.  Unfortunately, they sometimes open a spreadsheet without
closing them.  (E. G. when debugging a program.)

At that point the spreadsheet is locked and I have to copy it to a new
name.  This is even if I not only stop the program but even shut down
Visual Studio applications.

Example, here is a simple program that opens and closes a spreadsheet.
I can run it as many times as I wish.

```
    Imports System.IO
    Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim A As Excel.Application
    A = New Excel.Application
    Dim eW As Excel.Workbook : Dim C As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NAME As String
    NAME = "c:\a\TEE.xlsx"
    eW = A.Workbooks.Open(NAME)
    Console.WriteLine()
    C = eW.Sheets.Item(1) ' student individual grade sheet
    Console.WriteLine(C.Cells(1, 1).value)
    eW.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    Console.ReadLine() ' so we can see thescreen

End Sub
End Module

Let's say I have injected a defect , and thus my program does not close the
Excel spreadsheet as it should,  e. g.

Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim A As Excel.Application
    A = New Excel.Application
    Dim eW As Excel.Workbook : Dim C As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NAME As String
    NAME = "c:\a\TEE.xlsx"
    Dim Q As Integer : Dim R As Integer : Dim Z As Integer
    Q = 5 : R = 0
    eW = A.Workbooks.Open(NAME)
    Console.WriteLine()
    C = eW.Sheets.Item(1) ' student individual grade sheet
    Console.WriteLine(C.Cells(1, 1).value)
    Z = Q Mod R
    eW.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    Console.ReadLine() ' so we can see the screen

End Sub
```

Now, when I run the original applicaton (presumably, I have removed the bug):
I can run the original application as nothing was changed.

If my application changes something, I get a file save dialogue from Excel
with a file Name of `"Copy of TEE.xlsx"

Here is the example program:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Module Module1
Sub Main()
    Dim A As Excel.Application
    A = New Excel.Application
    Dim eW As Excel.Workbook : Dim C As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim NAME As String
    NAME = "c:\a\TEE.xlsx"
    Dim Q As Integer : Dim R As Integer : Dim Z As Integer
    Q = 5 : R = 0
    eW = A.Workbooks.Open(NAME)
    Console.WriteLine()
    C = eW.Sheets.Item(1) ' student individual grade sheet
    Console.WriteLine(C.Cells(1, 1).value)
    Z = Q Mod R
    eW.Close(SaveChanges:=True)
    Console.ReadLine() ' so we can see thescreen

End Sub
```

(I face this challenge this in two different circumstances.

When I teach Visual Basic Programming,
I have labs and procedures where the students
write Visual BAsic Programs that do things with spreadsheets.  (These
parallel the laboratories I have that do things with one- and two-dimensional
arrays.)

Needless to say, the students have bugs, their files get locked, and this
distracts the students from the array processing logic concepts I am trying
to teach.

The second, is I am making programs that create and maintain individual
spreadsheets for each students grades (not that one).  They load each
spreadsheet, perform the processing and then close the file.  Needless to say,
I have bugs in them, and it is very distracting from the debugging
process to keep having to deal with these stupid dialogues.

So how can I best deal with this .

(I would like to tell Visual Basicc to tell Excel :
"I don't care if the Expletive-deleted file is locked,
save it anyway."
But beggars can't be choosers
Perhaps, I can get it to automatically save to the suggested name instead
of bothering me.

Comment: Luckily, I don't program VB, nor do I teach class. But couldn't you just supply an alternative file name programmatically in case of error, such as *MyWorkbook(1).xlsm*. You could then have a clean-up procedure to run when the dust has settled to replace *MyWorkbook.xlsm* with the highest index number of alternative files and delete all the extras.

Comment: This post discusses locked files in .Net: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304/how-to-check-for-file-lock/20623302#20623302  Also - To kill excel in Windows use `taskkill /IM "Excel.exe" /F`from the cmd line